# Totalling Troublesome T's

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic

Given a "T" shape on an x * y number grid, with length W on the top bar and H on the stem of the T, with the bottom of the T on the square numbered n: calculate the total of all of the numbers in the T shape. W must be an odd number and all must be positive integers.

Here are some examples of valid T's on a 9*9 grid:

[image: Examples]

Looking at the T where `n=32, W=3 & H=4`, you can see that the total is:
`4 + 5 + 6 + 14 + 23 + 32 = 84`.

## The Challenge

Your challenge is to create a program which, when given five positive integers, x, y, W, H and n, output the total of the T with those values (W must be odd, given an even number the program can output anything or even crash). The numbers may be inputted in any reasonable format. If the T does not fit on the given grid, then any output is acceptable.

## Example Code (Python 3.6.2)

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
W = int(input())
H = int(input())
n = int(input())

total = 0

#"Stem" of the T
for i in range(H - 1):
    total += n - (x * i) #Decrease increment by length of row each time

#Top of the T 
for i in range(-W//2 + 1, W//2 + 1): #Iterate over the width offset so that the center is zero
    total += (n - (x * (H - 1))) + i #Add the top squares on the T, one less to the left and one more to the right

print(total)
```

As with most challenges here this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the answer with the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Isn't y redundant information?

Comment: @JonathanAllan I'm presuming it needn't be a square grid in which case `y` would not be redundant. `x` & `y` together would define the grid, `n` defines the bottom of the T shape, and `W` & `H` together define the T shape's size.

Comment: [Better quality image](https://image.ibb.co/kQKnBv/1.png)

Comment: Oh, someone already edited. nvm...

Comment: @EngineerToast we are told `n` and `x` and told "If the T does not fit on the given grid, then any output is acceptable." so `y` may be inferred.

Comment: @JonathanAllan How do you know if T fits in the grid if you don't know what the grid *is*? Ah, I see now. You're saying we can just assume it fits because any output is allowed if it doesn't fit so outputting what the correct answer would be if it *did* fit is a valid output. Gotchya.

Comment: Is this challenge just asking to golf the formula `(2n-(h-1)y)h/2+(n-(h-1)y)(w-1)`?

Comment: There could be many ways to approach the challenge, there's probably a builtin for it in Mathematical.

Comment: In the example, is `H` equal to 3 or 4? That is, does it include the top bar?

Comment: H is equal to 4

Comment: Can you add some test cases, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

A construction technique, which ends up much like [Luis Mendo's MATL answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141923/53748)

```
Ḷ×ạ⁵µṪ×⁶+S
```

A full program taking `H`, `x`, `n`, `W` in that order (`y` may be appended if one so wishes).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//4bi2w5fhuqHigbXCteG5qsOX4oG2K1P///80/zn/MzL/Mw)**

#### How?

```
Ḷ×ạ⁵µṪ×⁶+S - Main link: H, x
Ḷ          - lowered range                         [0,1,2,...,H-2,H-1]
 ×         - multiply (vectorises)                 [0,x,2x,...,(H-2)x,(H-1)x]
   ⁵       - program's 5th argument (3rd input)    n
  ạ        - absolute difference (vectorises)      [n,n-x,n-2x,...,n-(H-2)x,n-(H-1)x]
           -  (note: for an in-range T n>(H-1)x)   (cells of the stem)
    µ      - monadic chain separation (call this stem)
     Ṫ     - tail (pop from AND modify stem)       n-(H-1)x
           -                                       (cell at intersection of stem and top)
       ⁶   - program's 6th argument (4th input)    W
      ×    - multiply                              Wn-W(H-1)x
           -                                       (total value of the top)
         S - sum (the modified stem)               n+n-x+n-2x+...+n-(H-2)x
           -                                       (total value of the stem w/o top cell)
        +  - add (add top to the stem w.o top cell)
```

Answer (score 9):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>32</s> 30 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Shaggy*

```
(w,h,x)=>Q=n=>--h?n+Q(n-x):n*w
```

Takes input in a curried format: `f(W,H,x,y)(n)`

```js
let f =
(w,h,x)=>Q=n=>--h?n+Q(n-x):n*w;

console.log(
  f(3, 4, 9, 9)(32)
);
```

#### How?

First we note that the sum of the T starting at **n** with height **H** can be broken down into two sums:

- **n**
- The sum of the T starting one row higher with height **H - 1**

By repeatedly adding **n** to the total, moving one row up, and subtracting **1** from **H** until it reaches **1**, we end up summing the vertical stem of the T. Moving one row up is accomplished by subtracting **x** from **n**, since it can be observed that the difference between any cell and the one above is **x**.

When **H** reaches **1**, we now have only the crossbar of width **W** left to sum. At this point **n** represents the center of the crossbar. We *could* sum the crossbar recursively as we did with the stem, but instead we take advantage of a fairly simple formula:

```
sum(n - a : n + a) = (n - a) + (n - (a-1)) + ... + n + ... + (n + (a-1)) + (n + a)
                   = (n - a) + (n + a) + (n - (a-1)) + (n + (a-1)) + ... + n
                   = 2n + 2n + ... + n
                   = n * (2a + 1)
```

In this case, our **a** is **(W - 1) / 2**, which makes

```
n * (2a + 1) = n * (((W - 1) / 2) * 2 + 1)
             = n * ((W - 1) + 1)
             = n * W
```

which is the sum of the crossbar.

Comment: Seeing as you don't use `y` you just go with `(x,w,h)=>Q=n=>` and then call it using `f(x,w,h)(n,y)`? Seem to remember this coming up on Meta recently but can't remember the outcome.

Comment: @Shaggy Thank you, found a better format for that trick :-)

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (Visual C# Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), <s>64</s> 52 bytes

```cs
(x,y,W,H,n)=>{for(y=0;H-->1;n-=x)y+=n;return y+W*n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bcyxCsIwEIDh2TxFxsReRa1LiekiiINOFjqHeEpAr9JLxVD67BUHN/n51t9z7tlPPQe6yXPiiA8jyD2Qn86jjIPwd8csI@IgOLoYvNz35LeBIvxRyVraSb0hQQMHIG2r4dp2KtmlOeR5tTKU27dOmSXTYew7kilr5mTGyfz@rzZc5MkFUnoQs11L3N5x0XQh4jEQqlqVUEIBGyjWWhsxfps@)

The non-recursive answer did indeed turn out significantly shorter. Gross misuse of for loops and the fact that `y` is officially a mandatory input even though it's not used.

Comment: Should `return y+3*n;` be `return y+W*n`? Otherwise you wouldn't need to pass in `W`.

Comment: @Ayb4btu ... You know, I've actually had to fix that mistake multiple times along the way. I don't know how it keeps getting back in.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 38 bytes

```python
lambda x,W,H,n:~-H*(x*(1-H/2-W)+n)+W*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFCJ1zHQyfPqk7XQ0ujQkvDUNdD30g3XFM7T1M7XCvvf0FRZl6JRpqGpY6xjomOsZGm5n8A)

-4 bytes thanks to Jonathan Allan
-4 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen/Ayb4btu

Comment: EDIT: four bytes ...Save two bytes with our old friend tilde `lambda x,W,H,n:n*H-x*H*~-H/2+~-W*(n-H*x+x)` (FYI the TIO link has too many args in the call to `f`)

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh whoops thanks. And yay thanks! :D

Comment: @LuisMendo Wait whoops I fixed that but forgot to update the link and then un-fixed it when golfing. Thanks!

Comment: `lambda x,W,H,n:~-H*(x*(1-H/2-W)+n)+W*n` is 4 bytes shorter. (Credit goes to [_@Ayb4btu_'s C# .NET answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141978/52210).)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Oh cool, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
:q*-t0)iq*hs
```

Inputs are: `H`, `x`, `n`, `W`.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/36pQS7fEQDOzUCuj@P9/Ey5LLmMjLmMA)

#### Explanation

```
:     % Implicit input: H. Push [1, 2, ..., H]
q     % Subtract 1. Gives [0, 1, ..., H-1]
*     % Implicit input: x. Multiply. Gives [0, x, ..., x*(H-1)]
-     % Implicit input: n. Subtract. Gives [n-0, n-x, ..., n-x*(H-1)]. This is
      % the stem, bottom to top
t     % Duplicate
0)    % Get last element, that is, n-x*(H-1). This is the center top of the "T"
i     % Input: W
q     % Subtract 1
*     % Multiply. Gives n-x*(H-1)*(w-1). This is the sum of the vertical bar
      % excluding its center, which is already accounted for in the stem
h     % Concatenate into a row vector
s     % Sum of vector. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>18 16</s>  15 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

-1 byte thanks to [Erik the Outgolfer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41024/erik-the-outgolfer) (use of chain separator)

```
S’×⁵_ðc2Ḣ+⁸’P¤×
```

A full program taking `[H,W]`, `x`, `n` in that order (you can add `y` to the arguments if you like, it's not used).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9qZWxsef//U@KAmcOX4oG1X8OwYzLhuKIr4oG44oCZUMKkw5f///9bNCwzXf85/zMy)**

#### How?

The total is:

- `n` multiplied by the number of squares used in the **T** (which is `W+H-1`)
- minus the width of the grid, `x`, times the triangle number of the
  height (`1+2+3+...+h`) to account for the lack as we go up the stem
- minus the width of the grid, `x`, times one less that the height (`H-1`)
  times one less that the width (`W-1`) to account for the lack at the
  top of the **T**, excluding the lack we already accounted for at the top of the stem.

That is:

```
(W + H - 1) * n - ((H - 1) * (W - 1) + Triangle(H)) * x
```

The triangle number of `H` is its binomial with **2** A.K.A. `H-choose-2`.

```
c2Ḣ+⁸’P¤× - Link 1: the x * (Triangle(H) + (H-1)*(W-1)): [H,W]; x    
S’×⁵_ðc2Ḣ+⁸’P¤× - Main link: [H,W], x
S               - sum                                    H+W
 ’              - decrement                              H+W-1
   ⁵            - program's fifth argument (3rd input)   n
  ×             - multiply                               (H+W-1)*n
     ð          - dyadic chain separation
      c2        - choose-2 (vectorises)                  [Triangle(H), Triangle(W)]
        Ḣ       - head                                   Triangle(H)
             ¤  - nilad followed by link(s) as a nilad:
           ⁸    -    chain's left argument               [H,W]
           ’    -    decrement (vectorises)              [H-1,W-1]
            P   -    product                             (H-1)*(W-1)
         +      - add                                    (H-1)*(W-1)+Triangle(H)
              × - multiply (by chain's right arg, x)     ((H-1)*(W-1)+Triangle(H))*x
    _           - subtract                               (H+W-1)*n-((H-1)*(W-1)+Triangle(H))*x
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 52 bytes

```perl
($x,$y,$w,$h,$n)=<>;say$h*($n+$x*(.5-$h/2-$w))+$w*$n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcJLCoAgFAXQeeu4A/@V4UD67KBFNAgMQqMCc/O9iHOO9dwdEcOjUBSyQlCIfBym/loKgmCIEo9gxmmE2mpkziWyQCTyla@6n33TcW8pXqRnZ5q2@QA)

Comment: Do yoy need to take `y` as input, seeing as you're not using it?

Comment: Not really, but it was part of the input spec, so I included it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 38 bytes

```python
lambda x,W,H,n:~-H*(n-x*(W-1+H/2))+n*W
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaFCJ1zHQyfPqk7XQ0sjT7dCSyNc11DbQ99IU1M7Tyv8f0FRZl6JRpqGpY6xjomOMVD4PwA)

[HyperNeutrino's arithmetic expression](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141921/20260) with improved grouping.

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <strike>49</strike> 37 bytes

```cs
(x,y,W,H,n)=>~-H*(x*(1-H/2d-W)+n)+W*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hcw9C4JAGMDxufsUN97pYy/am5guQTgUBAnOdh5xYM@Bd4Yi9tWNhpaGGv7bj78wntC1HBuj8EYvnbHyHhFRFcbQc0@MLawS9NCg2Cm08F2pm2slE5rRmI6shQ5ySAF5nDy91GGtwxZeOvNLL@cucjd3cIzI5/rQqqSnQiHjpCeTvUajKznNa2XlUaFkGQshhACWEPicR79IAOvVH7KB7fxNBjKMLw)

A direct formula avoiding the need for looping or recursion. Unfortunately I had to use `2d` otherwise it was going to do integer division and truncate the fractional component. The `y` param is completely redundant and could be removed.

#### Explanation

```cs
(n-x*(H-1))*W             // Calculates the Top of the T
```

`(n-x*(H-1))` gets the cell index by subtracting from `n` the number of rows to go up multiplied by the grid width. Multiplying this by `W` gets the sum of the top bar of the T.

```cs
n*(H-1)-x*(H-2)*(H-1)/2   // Calculates the Stem of the T
```

I got this by using mathematical induction by trying to calculate the sum of *1, 10, 19, 28* where `n=28, H=4, x=9`. Which can be written as:

```cs
28 + (28-9) + (28-9-9) + (28-9-9-9)
28-9*0 + 28-9*1 + 28-9*2 + 28-9*3
28*4 -9*(0+1+2+3)
n*H -x*(1+2+3)
n*H -x*(3*(3+1)/2)
n*H -x*((H-1)*((H-1)+1)/2)
n*H -x*((H-1)*H/2)
```

but because we don't want to include the top cell of the stem (included in the formula for the Top of the T), `H` needs to be `H-1`. Making the formula

```cs
n*(H-1)-x*((H-2)*(H-1)/2)
```

Combining these two formulas gives

```cs
(n-x*(H-1))*W + n*(H-1)-x*((H-2)*(H-1)/2)
```

and simplifying it gives the formula used for the answer (though how it is rearranged can change how it looks).

#### Acknowledgements

Saved 12 bytes thanks to Kevin Cruijssen. Though I'm not sure if the `;` should be included or not.

Comment: You can golf some things: `=>{return ...}` can be `=>...`; and `(H-1)` can be `~-H`. So in total: [`(x,y,W,H,n)=>~-H*(x*(1-H/2d-W)+n)+W*n` - **37 bytes**](https://tio.run/##hcw9C4JAGMDxufsUN97pYy/am5guQTgUBAnOdh5xYM@Bd4Yi9tWNhpaGGv7bj78wntC1HBuj8EYvnbHyHhFRFcbQc0@MLawS9NCg2Cm08F2pm2slE5rRmI6shQ5ySAF5nDy91GGtwxZeOvNLL@cucjd3cIzI5/rQqqSnQiHjpCeTvUajKznNa2XlUaFkGQshhACWEPicR79IAOvVH7KB7fxNBjKMLw)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks, that's a huge saving, I'm not sure how I missed them...

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://pyth.readthedocs.io), 23 bytes

```
+-*KEQ**JEQctQ2*tE-K*Jt
```

**[Try it here!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%2B-%2aKEQ%2a%2aJEQctQ2%2atE-K%2aJt&input=4%0A32%0A9%0A3&debug=0)** (note the order of the inputs)

## How?

```
+-*KEQ**JEQctQ2*tE-K*Jt    Full program. Q is input, E is evaluated input (reads a new line)

  *KEQ                     The second input * the first input.
       *JEQ                The third input * the first input.
           ctQ2            Float division of the the first input decremented by 1, by 2.
      *                    Product.
 -                         Difference.
                tE         The fourth input.
                    *Jt    The product of the third input and the first input decremented by 1...
                 -K        ... Subtracted from the second input
               *           Product.
+                          Sum.
                           Output implicitly.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), 14 bytes

I tried a few different solutions based on [ETH's observations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141915/58974) but the shortest I've come up with (so far) is a straight port.

Takes input in the order `n,H,W,x`.

```
´V©ßXnU)+UªU*W
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=tFap31huVSkrVapVKlc=&input=MzIsNCwzLDk=)

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 35 bytes

```
(x,W,H,n)->~-H*(x*(1-H/2d-W)+n)+W*n
```

Port of [*@Ayb4btu* .Net C# answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/141978/52210), after I golfed it a bit.

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##LY4/D4IwEMV3P8WNLbQYwcUQnVlkYWAwDrVUU4SDQCEYg18dy5/k7pdc3r28l4te8KpWmGfvSRaibeEqNH53ABqNap5CKojnEyCrukehQBKrwMBmpgujhUhD@zbatdMaYbSEGBDOMJGBpSxiSPnlxyOHDA458GjvZzylLlI3dXAKV2NtM6xx8/eVzqC0hUhiGo2v2x0EXdskn9ao0qs649VWMgUS9CQ5sYAdWeDTrc04/QE)

---

If `y` is a mandatory input-parameter, it will be **37 bytes** instead ([Try it here](https://tio.run/##LY5PD4IwDMXvfooeN@gw/rkQomcucvHAwXiYY5ohFiLDQIx@9TmQpP0lzetrXylfUtSNprK4O1XJtoWDNPReABiy@nmVSkM2jgBF3V0qDYp5BXocOUzMJ6YTiSd@@ePbV2ulNQoyINiBYz0OmGOKxMX@K9KA9QFbiXS5LkTOQ@JhHpBL/tbG//LW@cKrNgU8fDB2tE9Dt9MZJP@nOg6t1Y@o7mzUeMlWxChSLMYYN7jFzZrPiT7uBw)):

```
(x,y,W,H,n)->~-H*(x*(1-H/2d-W)+n)+W*n
```

If outputting a double isn't allowed, it will be **40 bytes** instead ([Try it here](https://tio.run/##LY47D4IwFIV3f8UdW2gxgoshOrPIwsBgHGpBU4QLgUIwBv96LY/k3i@5j3NyCjEIXjc5FtnbyFJ0HVyFwu8OQKHO26eQOcTzuCxAkpkjm5kujBYiDe3PZNtWp4VWEmJAOIMhI0tZxJDyy49HDhmd2YOSA4/2fsZT6iJ1UwdNuKqb/lFa9WYy1CqDykYiiW4Vvm53EHTNk3w6nVde3WuvsSddIkFPkhML2JEFPt0iTeYP)):

```
(x,W,H,n)->~-H*(x*(int)(1-H/2d-W)+n)+W*n
```

If having a function instead of a full program isn't allowed, it will be **160 bytes** instead ([Try it here](https://tio.run/##TYyxDoIwFEV/pWMLFhVYDGHHwYmhA@nQ0CcphFcCFWMI/nrt4EDudE5Obq9Wxe0E2OvBe4MO5qdqgTy2xSlnWrJao8moDNLazQa7Riq23UPXwUxEifAmf6KqSSU7VaVINLRWQxBZEHgUuWRF/VkcjIl9uWQKl45@eRXRQ3SRLKJXXp1TzQWLkcUiQlbsu/f@Fpb53GfpDw)):

```
interface M{static void main(String[]a){Integer W=new Integer(a[2]),H=W.decode(a[3]),n=W.decode(a[4]);System.out.print(~-H*(W.decode(a[0])*(1-H/2d-W)+n)+W*n);}}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), <s>100</s> <s>99</s> <s>96</s> 91 bytes

```java
x->W->H->n->{int t=n,i=0,j=-W/2;for(;++i<H;t+=n-x*i);for(;j<W/2;t+=n-x*~-H+j++);return-~t;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nY89T8MwFEX3/AqPcR27qLAgJxlROjB16IAYTJpGzyS25bxU/VD614MLBjH3TVfnXj3paHVQ3LrG6N3nDL2zHokOTIwIndiPpkawRixkkrjxo4Oa1J0aBvKqwJBLQuINqDB0L3Gfrw02beOzO0kMZThyJsV85OWWlxUvDS8vYJBgYTIoHjJd8O1yJffWp5IxyCuJrDD8uAD6A3V@6yO88oppxqj0DY7e8CvKaQ5mN4NoF0UOFnakD47pBj2Y9u2dKN8O9J/y5jRg0ws7onBhgulZKOe6U/pMY3j8DU9/ZEWp/P4wJdP8BQ)

Comment: When using two parameters currying is shorter; when using three parameters currying is the same length; but when using four or more parameters currying is actually longer. So you can replace `x->W->H->n->` with `(x,W,H,n)->`, [like this](https://tio.run/##LY@xboMwEIZ3nuJGOzZuk3SJHDqzNEsGhqqDSyAyhTMyR0QT8ezUJr3hk@7zL53/xtxM6voKm8vPYrveeYImODWSbVU9YknWodropGzNMMCHsfhIACxS5WtTVnCK6yrgziInGVmszFci1yEzJwEDGbIlnAAhg4VNspC5RJ6@P2KQMpQ2e5VNlhYvO107z7QQ9phrEhmm08byp2yO8T1IFi3L0y3nohGCa1/R6BFIbPW86GT9Wz9@t@Ho/@2bsxfoQg92Jm/x@vkFxl8H/uwR5/w7UNUpN5LqQ4IYqjs7yL18k/sdX8vEOvPyBw).

Comment: Also, you can save some additional bytes by changing `t+=(n-x*(H-1))+j++` to `t+=n-x*~-H+j++` so you don't need the four parenthesis. And `return t+1;` can be `return-~t;` so you don't need the space. [Here is the relevant codegolfing tip post for using `-~` and `~-` with more information.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/67630/52210)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thank you, I'm just using currying because I don't know if the bytes of the functional interface are counted

Answer (score 0):

## [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 32 bytes

```
[0,:-1|i=:-(a*:)┘g=g+i}?i*:+g-i
```

This takes parameters in the order `h, n, x, w`, and `y` is ignored.

### Explanation

Each time a variable is read from the cmd line in QBIC, using the `:` command, it is assigned a letter (a-z). For clarity, I will use `h, n, x, w` in the explanation instead of the `b,c,d,e` they would be assigned (`a` gets taken by the FOR-loop).

```
First, we want to know the total of the stem
[0,h-1|     FOR a = 0 to the height - 1
  i=n-(a*x)     helper i holds an increment value: this is n, minus the 
                grid-width once for every row we go up.
  g=g+i         helper g is incremented by i for each row
  }         NEXT
  ?         PRINT
   i*w          the center on the top bar times the width (ie the average)
   -i           corrected for that ione i we already counted in the stem
   +g           plus the stem itself
```